# How to check for second element with class name and click it if it exists in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

So I am writing automation tests using selenium and I am having a lot of trouble selecting the second element in a list of divs with the same class names

```
Boolean isExists2Accounts = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//div[contains(@class, 'item-name')])[2]")).size() < 0;

                                if(isExists2Accounts)
                                {
                                    //Finds second div element that has classname of item-name and clicks on it
                                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[contains(@class, 'item-name')])[2]")).click();
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    driver.get("javascript:alert('There isn't a second account or you don't know how to select it!');");
                                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                                    org.testng.Assert.fail("transferTest6() Failed due to There isn't a second account or you don't know how to select it!");
                                }
```

HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="item-list">
    <div class="item-name">
        <div> clickable area </div>
        <div class="button-wrap"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-name">
        <div> clickable area </div>
        <div class="button-wrap"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-name">
        <div> clickable area</div>
        <div class="button-wrap"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-name">
        <div> clickable area </div>
        <div class="button-wrap"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not really sure what I am doing wrong here, I looked at the html and there are 5 divs with the specified class name. Very new to selenium in general, using eclipse/junit/webdriver.

I have seen several questions similiar to this, and trying solutions people have posted have not worked. I have seen some suggestions to use .get(2) and I will try and implement that in the mean time.

Any help you could give would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get(2) is THIRD element, not the second, as the countage begins from 0.

So:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".item-name")).get(1).click();
```

OR depending on where is yr clickable

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".item-name div:not(.button-wrap)")).get(1).click();
```

Comment: This line did not work:

     driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".item-name")).get(1).click();

It is not clicking the item name. It instead triggers an error clause that I have due to missing data that should appear after the click.

Comment: Added html structure to original question.

Comment: Does the structure of my HTML edit your answer? The clickable area is within the div that says "clickable area"

Comment: Hey still doesn't seem to want to click on that div, I might try and come at this from a javascript perspective instead. The webdriver lets you send javascript directly to the browser, ideally I wouldn't have to do this but I want to try and get this finished. Thanks for your help.

Comment: open chrome dev tools -> Elements -> now right click on the needed element. What is highlighted?

Comment: The line that says: <div> clickable area </div>

Comment: heavy artillery is going to come. Try  `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".item-list .item-name:nth-of-type(2) div:not(.button-wrap)")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

Hey all the answer that was given by Stanjer works, I tested it with different markup, the developer that built the system I am testing through a random mousedown event (not click) for the html I am trying to interact with which was causing the problem.

So final solution with problem if it was a click event would be:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".item-name")).get(1).click();
```

Just like he said.

However in this case I am instead going to send Javascript to the console to work with functions that have already been created by the developer.